# OpenLayers drag event slow to respond (hard to move)

Tags: openlayers

[image]
We have an application that loads data from the postgis and draws on the map in layers of vectors. When many elements are loaded, does the map get heavy to use the drag event, slow to respond to user interaction? Does it have to do with the amount of elements loaded on the map? I have seen applications with much more elements drawn but not so heavy for navigation with the drag event. The problem is only in the Drag event.

```
var DragZoom = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
    condition: ol.events.condition.always
});

Load Feature on map (we have many:
$.ajax({
            url: '/Map/GetPolygonsByQuadrante/',
            beforeSend: Processando("Obtendo dados..."),
            data: JSON.stringify({
                MinLat: MinLat1,
                MinLong: MinLong1,
                MaxLat: MaxLat1,
                MaxLong: MaxLong1,
                NivelZoom: NivZoom
            }),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (dataFromServer) {
                ClearLayerFromMap(VectorPolygon);
                MessLbl("lblMessage", "Ok!");
                try {
                    var estilo;
                    Polygons = new Array(dataFromServer.length);
                    // Loop over each object
                    for (var $i = 0; $i < dataFromServer.length; $i++) {
                        var ativo = GetVisibleByLayer(dataFromServer[$i].Tipo);
                        if (ativo === true) {
                            var object = dataFromServer[$i];
                            //verifica se o o layer existe
                            //adiciona a linha num array do mapara para posterior identificação
                            var pol = {
                                Id: object.Id,
                                Tipo: object.Tipo,
                                Pontos: object.Pontos
                            };
                            Polygons[$i] = pol;
                            var coordinates = null;
                            coordinates = [object.Pontos.length + 1]; //tem que voltar ao polygono noi ponto inicial
                            for (var $t = 0; $t < object.Pontos.length; $t++) {
                                coordinates[$t] = [object.Pontos[$t].Longitude, object.Pontos[$t].Latitude];
                            }
                            coordinates[length - 1] = [object.Pontos[0].Longitude, object.Pontos[0].Latitude];
                            estilo = GetStyleByLayer(object.Tipo);
                            var init = 'pol-';
                            DrawPolygon(init + object.Id, estilo, coordinates, SourcePolygon);
                        }
                    }
                    ProcessandoClose();
                    MessLbl("lblMessage", "Tot. polígonos:  " + dataFromServer.length.toLocaleString('pt-BR'));
                    ProcessandoClose();
                    AtualizandoMapa = false;
                    map.render();
                } catch (e) {
                    MessLbl("lblMessage", "...");
                    ProcessandoClose();
                    TrataErro(e);
                }
            },
            error: function (json) {
                if (json !== undefined > 0 && json.responseText === "secao_invalida") {
                    window.location.href = "/Home/";
                } else {
                    MessLbl("lblMessage", "...");
                    ProcessandoClose();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Performance can also be affected by how you style the features.  A style function should cache styles to avoid creating new styles on each call.

Comment: We did a review on the styles and really were very diverse. We feel a better performance. We also find that it has a relationship with the amount of data. Thank you!